# User profile service application status starting in sharepoint 2016

Tags: 2016, user-profile-service

I have an intranet farm with 2 application, 3 WFE servers there is user profile service running in 3 servers one app and in 2 wfe servers.

In central administraton>Manage service applications user profile service application status showing starting and I cannot create new synchronization connections.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following:

```
$sa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ?{$_.TypeName -match 'Profile'}
$sa.Status = 'Online'
$sa.Update()
```

Comment: i get the above error please check The property 'Status' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $sa.Status = 'Online'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: service status showing online and provisioning

Answer (score -1):

There is a really fantastic article written by harbar for sp 2010 which applies even to 2016 on this topic . Go through the list of steps in it and it will almost always fix the issue for you - http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx